# KeyValuePair - no parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object that has a KeyValuePair type property.

I would like to read some data from a database and store results in this KeyValuePair type field.

```
myObject.KeyValuePairs = ctx.ExecuteQuery<KeyValuePair<String, int>>
                        ("Select " +
                            "[" + q.Name + "] As [Key]" +
                            ", Count([" + q.Name + "]) As [Value] From SomeTable" + 
                            " Group By [" + q.Name + "]").ToList();
```

`myObject.KeyValuePairs` is a `List<KeyValuePair<String, int>>`

When I attempt to read the records I get the following exception:

The type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Int32]' must declare a default (parameterless) constructor in order to be constructed during mapping.

I have a default constructor in a class, but this is not fixing the problem. It looks as if It doesn't know how to construct a KeyValuePair object. Doesn't it have a default constructor? Confused..

Thank you

Comment: Please parametrize your sql Bobby Tables....

Comment: @BFree: +1 for http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It does have a public parameterless constructor because `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is a struct and all struct have implicit public parameterless constructor.

**The issue is that EF can't find it by reflection because reflection does not return the default constructor for struct.**

This is why EF is reporting that it can't find it (it can't find it by reflection).

Additionally, even if you could use the default constructor by reflection, `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is immutable and so you can't set the `Key` and `Value` after construction.

To solve your problem, define a custom class

```
class NameCount {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and change your query to return the `Key` as `Name` and `Value` as `Count`. I assume that you can come up with a better name for your custom class.

Comment: var f = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(); <--- this compiles just fine... All structs have a default parameter less constructor by default: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @BFree: It's rather obnoxious that I forgot that since I had coded a method a few weeks ago `HasDefaultConstructor(this Type type)` and obviously my unit testing found a bug when `type.IsValueType` was true so I had to add the logic `if(this.IsValueType) { return true; }`.

Comment: @Jason: Eh, don't beat yourself up, how often are we writing structs anyway, it's an easy one to overlook....

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you

Comment: Why not use fields rather than properties?  Is there *any* advantage to using properties to wrap a struct field in a mutable property?  Properties can add overhead which is usually slight, but can be substantial when using nested properties.  Wrapping class fields in properties can be advantageous in a number of circumstances, but the circumstances aren't applicable to struct properties.  From what I can tell, struct properties add overhead without adding any useful semantics, so why bother with them?